# How to pass parent function to child screen in React Navigation 5?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

Recently I have started using React Native `0.61.5` and React navigation `5.x`. Now I need to pass a parent function into a child screen. For example, I want to change navbar icon by pressing button in tab of TabNavigator nested in StackNavigator. Previously (navigation ver. 3.x) I was using `getActiveChildNavigationOptions` for my needs but now it's removed. So the only way to achieve this goal is to pass custom functions to child components.

Here in example code I want to change from `XXXXXXXX` to `YYYYYYYYY`:

```js
const TabA = ({ route }) => (
  <View>
    <Text>Tab A</Text>
      <Button 
        title="Change header"
        onPress={() => route.params.setHeaderRightName("YYYYYYYYY")}/>
  </View>
)

const TabB = () => <><Text>Tab B</Text></>

const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator();
const TabsNavigator = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [headerRightName, setHeaderRightName] = useState("XXXXXXXX");

  useLayoutEffect(() => navigation.setOptions({
    headerRight: () => <MyNavIcon name={headerRightName}/>
  }), [headerRightName]);

  return (
    <Tabs.Navigator>
      <Tabs.Screen name="tab-a" component={TabA} initialParams={{ setHeaderRightName }} />
      <Tabs.Screen name="tab-b" component={TabB} />
    </Tabs.Navigator>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
export default App = () => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="tabs" component={TabsNavigator} />
      <Stack.Screen name="another-screen" component={AnotherScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
)
```

Everything is working fine, but I am getting this warning:

[image]

Full text:

```
Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state, which can break usage such as persisting and restoring state. This might happen if you passed non-serializable values such as function, class instances etc. in params. If you need to use components with callbacks in your options, you can use 'navigation.setOptions' instead. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting#i-get-the-warning-non-serializable-values-were-found-in-the-navigation-state for more details.
```

**So how can I pass function from parent to child if warning says I cannot pass function using route params?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The documentation page the link in the warning is pointing to says:

> If you don't use state persistence or deep link to the screen which accepts functions in params, then you can ignore the warning. To ignore it, you can use YellowBox.ignoreWarnings.

**So, in my case, I can ignore this warning and pass functions thought route params safely.**

```json
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
  'Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state',
]);
```

or for react native 0.63 and higher:

```json
LogBox.ignoreLogs([
  'Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state',
]);
```

Comment: @bmovement I hate solutions like this too. But even contributors made me sure this is the correct way.

Answer (score 7):

`YellowBox` is deprecated in react-native > 0.6. Use the following code and also remember this is not the main error. this is only a warning

```
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';
LogBox.ignoreLogs([
  'Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state',
]);
```

Oh. know its gone. Thank you

Note: And the above question is passed the setState const variable to the screen via `initialParams`. So we can't pass the functions or any other executable modules via `initialParams` and this is only pass the string type of data. So please use the following code for pass the functions, setvariables, etc...

```
const [HeaderRightName,setHeaderRightName] = React.useState('');
<Tabs.Screen name="tab-a" options={{ headerShown: false }} >
           {(props) => (
                <TabA setHeaderRightName={setHeaderRightName} {...props}/>
           )}
</Tabs.Screen
```

> 

Answer (score 2):

```
class MainScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: null
    };

    this.updateTitle = this.updateTitle.bind(this);
  }

  updateTitle(title) {
    this.setState({title: title});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen 
          name="NewScreen"
          options={{
            headerShown: true,
            headerTitle: this.state.title
          }}>
            {(props) => <NewScreen  {...props} updateTitle={this.updateTitle}/>}
          </Stack.Screen>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```